# json to csv convert in Python returns single row?

Tags: python, json, csv

I recently got help from stackoverflow and corrected my script to convert json to csv. However, now the script is returning only one single row, kindly suggest the modifications in the below code, so that I could convert and have the entire json file to csv.

Below is a snippet from my json file. It has nested content for "courses", where some of the course values are there while it is null for some.

```
[{
    "address": " Vidyanagar, Hubli-580031", 
    "college": "College (Architecture)", 
    "courses": [], 
    "email": " principal@bvb.edu", 
    "fax": "0836-2374985", 
    "name": "School Of Architecturebv Bhoomaradi College Of Engg. & Technology", 
    "phone": "0836-2378123, 2378201", 
    "recognition": " V.t.u. Belgaum", 
    "website": ""
},{
    "address": " Udyambag, Belgaum-590008", 
    "college": "Institute (Architecture)", 
    "courses": [], 
    "email": " principal@git.edu", 
    "fax": "0831-2441909", 
    "name": "School Of Architecturelaw Society's Gogte Institute Of Technology", 
    "phone": "0831-2441104, 2405507", 
    "recognition": " V.t.u. Belgaum", 
    "website": ""
},{
    "address": " Vidya Southa, Gokula Extn. Post, Bantwal-560054", 
    "college": "Institute (Architecture)", 
    "courses": [], 
    "email": " hod_at@msrit.edu", 
    "fax": "080-23603124", 
    "name": "School Of Architecturems Ramaiah Institute Of Technology ", 
    "phone": "080-23606934, 23600822", 
    "recognition": " V.t.u. Belgaum", 
    "website": ""
},{
    "address": " -, Gulbarga-585102", 
    "college": "College (Architecture)", 
    "courses": [
        {
            "brief_details": "", 
            "college_name": "School of ArchitecturePoojya Doddappa Appa College of Engineering", 
            "course_branch": "B.Arch", 
            "course_duration": " 5-year", 
            "course_nature": " Full-Time", 
            "course_title": "", 
            "course_type": " B.Arch", 
            "no_of_seats": " 60", 
            "qualifications": "", 
            "selection_process": ""
        }
    ], 
    "email": " principal@pdaengg.com", 
    "fax": "08472-255685", 
    "name": "School Of Architecturepoojya Doddappa Appa College Of Engineering", 
    "phone": "08472-224262 Extn. 435, 220742", 
    "recognition": " V.t.u. Belgaum", 
    "website": ""
},{
    "address": " R.v. Vidyaniketan P.o., Mysore Road, Bangalore-560059", 
    "college": "College (Architecture)", 
    "courses": [
        {
            "brief_details": "", 
            "college_name": "School of ArchitectureR.V. College of Engineering", 
            "course_branch": "B.Arch", 
            "course_duration": " 5-year", 
            "course_nature": " Full-Time", 
            "course_title": "", 
            "course_type": " B.Arch", 
            "no_of_seats": " 20", 
            "qualifications": "", 
            "selection_process": ""
        }
    ], 
    "email": " architecture@rvce.ac.in", 
    "fax": "080-28602914, 28602148, 28600337", 
    "name": "School Of Architecturer.v. College Of Engineering", 
    "phone": "080-28602170, 28601258, 28600184", 
    "recognition": " V.t.u. Belgaum", 
    "website": "www.rvce.ac.in"
}
```

And below is my code:

```
import json
import csv

def write_csv(jsonfile, outfile):

    with open(jsonfile) as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    college_dict = data[0]

    college_keys = list(college_dict.keys())
    college_keys.remove('courses')
    college_keys.remove('college')

    courses_dict = data[0]['courses'][0] if data[0]['courses'] else {'brief_details' : None}
    courses_keys = list(courses_dict.keys())
    courses_keys.remove('brief_details')

    with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        headers = college_keys + courses_keys
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)

        row = (
            [
                college_dict[key] if college_dict[key] else 'NA'
                for key in college_keys
            ] 
            + 
            [
                courses_dict[key] if courses_dict[key] else 'NA'
                for key in courses_keys
            ]
        )

        csv_writer.writerow(row)

jsonfile = '/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/collegesdb/collegesdb1.json'
outfile = '/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/collegesdb/collegesout.csv'

write_csv(jsonfile, outfile)
```

This json file is huge, but below is the resulted csv:

```
website,fax,name,phone,address,email,recognition
NA,0836-2374985,School Of Architecturebv Bhoomaradi College Of Engg. & Technology,"0836-2378123, 2378201"," Vidyanagar, Hubli-580031", principal@bvb.edu, V.t.u. Belgaum
```

Comment: The code is handling only the first item: `college_dict = data[0]`

Comment: any solutions for handling the entire file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code converts only the first item `data[0]`. You need to iterate the `data`.

```
...

with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    headers = college_keys + courses_keys
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for d in data:
        row = (
            [d[key] or 'NA' for key in college_keys] +
            [d[key] or 'NA' for key in courses_keys]
        )
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

 ...
```

Comment: It still returns one single row, but a different one.

Comment: I think this code is extremely crippled, the file is really huge some 300MB with 70k + values, I am sure now I will have to do it either manually or write another script. However thanks for all your help. That was really nice of you.

Comment: @downvoter, What's wrong with the answer? How can I improve the answer?

Comment: Your answer is fine, it just does not work for the entire file. The result you showed is just 4-5 lines. There is a problem with my code and my approach not in your answer. I will have to write a different script.